# Overheating laptop

Tags: kernel

i've been using ubuntu for ~2 months, 
when i installed it on my computer (laptop) it never overheat
but a day, i don't know what happened, it over heated.. (70*C @ Idle)
I've tryed what ever i found on the net, and as well, i can't change the CPU freq o.O, i5 M460 @ 2.53 GHz..
i have benn trying, jupiter (no result), lm-sensors (aswell), and the cpu freq thingy for unity (cpu wont move from 2.5GHz)
Any help?

(i'm a C++ user and PHP coder...)

Answer (score 1):

Your computer's heatsink has probably got clogged. You can clean it by blowing through the heat vent of your computer.
Or, you could dis-assemble your laptop and do a thorough cleaning of the heatsink. This procedure differs for different laptops.

Also make sure you have got the latest kernels and updates. Sometimes kernels have overheating/heat regression bugs.

Comment: about the heatsnik, i cleaned it many times without succses, and yup i  got the last kernel (3.0 or something) and last updates, Ubuntu 11.10 ofcourse..

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10? Try upgrade to 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at:

- Check to make sure the air vents are not clogged on both sides (cool air inlet, hot air exhaust).

  - It's important to check that when you clean them you don't push the dust/hair back into the heatsink.
- Are all the fans spinning up as expected when it gets warm?

  - If one fan is not working (i.e. slow or stopped), then the temp will probably rise.  Todays laptops don't have "extra" cooling capability, so if it has multiple fans, both are probably necessary.
- Can you boot from a bootable CD and use the system for a while to confirm it still gets warm?

  - It's possible an update to your system might have inadvertently disabled some part of the power settings.
- If all else fails, you will probably have to disassemble the laptop to check the heatsink and fans.

  - I've worked on systems that pulled in hair and dust but it got stuck inside and was impossible to remove without opening it up.

Comment: thanks guys, it helps me, but why is my CPU freq blocked at max?

Comment: You might have to change that from the BIOS settings. Lower your multiplier and that should reduce clock speed.

Comment: i'm on a Dell laptop, not a desktop, and when i had a fresh install of ubuntu, it worked, but nowadays, it wont..

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem related to your graphic card adapter as well. It's your computer using a HybridGraphics? Do you use the open source drivers? If YES, than as I said previously the overheating problem it's a graphic card bug. Try using this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics and may fix your problem (had same problem with overheating and resolved it using that method).

Answer (score -1):

I am 100% sure you're issue is the hybrid graphics and I have finally managed to tame this issue in most overheating laptops out there. Here is the ugly but workable hack:

yes there is an ugly hack, which needs to be in place so that it shuts down your discrete graphics card on boot and will disable it on ubuntu. Which I think should be fine as it will totally chill your system

Step1. goto terminal (alt+ctrl+t) and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Step2. add the following lines before exit 0:

```
echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

So your rc.local would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

exit 0
```

Step3: Save and exit gedit, then type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Enter your password when required.

Basically what you did was, you switched to Integrated (IGD) graphics. then switched off the other one.