# Samsung Series 5 getting hot

Tags: overheating

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04.02 64bit on my Samsung however I noticed it is getting too hot :(

It has 2 VGAs (Intel HD4000 & Nvidia GT 630M 2GB) however I'm using only Intel. At least the nvidia* drivers are not loaded.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: PS: I've just upgraded to Quantal, however nothing changed.

Comment: Me too, I've the same problem with my samsung 5 series Ultrabook. I've asked the question the last year, but it seems to be a kernel bug or some thing like that.[cf. my previous question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152440/notebook-overheating). Hope you'll find an answer. Keep me informed please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Dell Studio XPS laptop with Ubuntu 11.04. Basically the kernel didn't have proper control of the CPU, and it would heat up very quickly unnecessarily. Once 12.04 came out, the fixes were there to solve the issue, and I no longer had to drag my fan around with me! Unfortunatly I don't know enough to point you in the direction of what exactly the issue is, but if you report the bug I'm sure someone will be able to get to the bottom of it!

Comment: I think I figured it out, right now the temp is really better. I'm still doing some tests, once I have a definitive position I'll share if it worked or not. But thanks!